# Kubernetes Ingress Nginx Service : AWS API Gateway/CloudFront returning 403

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, aws-api-gateway, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have been trying to use AWS API Gateway as externalName in kubernetes service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "aws-gateway"
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: 12345.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

But I keep getting 403 response as below

[image]

Can someone please help me, how to fix this.

Comment: Are you sure there is no firewall between the k8s cluster and the API GW ?

Comment: Yes, there are no firewalls.

Comment: Hi @krishna_5c3 — did you ever resolve this? Having a similar issue and getting the same type of error with an `ExternalName` service pointing to a Cloudfront distribution.